Apache Hudi - MOR | Getting same number of records in table and table_rt after each run
We are running an ingestion job on AWS-Glue using Pyspark which reads data from the source and writes it in HUDI | MOR.
The HUDI configurations that we are using are as follows:
"hoodie.table.name": "table",
"hoodie.datasource.write.table.type": "MERGE_ON_READ",
"hoodie.datasource.write.recordkey.field": ','.join([ str(x).lower().strip() for x in str(param['primary_key']).split(',')]),
"hoodie.datasource.write.partitionpath.field": param['table_partition_key'],
"hoodie.datasource.write.operation": "upsert",
                        
"hoodie.clustering.async.enabled":"true",
"hoodie.clustering.inline":"false",


"hoodie.compact.inline.trigger.strategy":"NUM_COMMITS",
"hoodie.datasource.compaction.async.enable": "true",
"hoodie.compact.inline":"true",
"hoodie.compact.inline.max.delta.commits": 5,

"hoodie.index.type": "BLOOM",
"hoodie.bloom.index.update.partition.path":"alse",

"hoodie.clean.automatic":"false",

"hoodie.parquet.compression.codec":"snappy",
"hoodie.upsert.shuffle.parallelism":100,
"hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.skip_ro_suffix":"true",
"hoodie.parquet.small.file.limit":50,
"hoodie.bulkinsert.shuffle.parallelism": 400,

"hoodie.datasource.write.precombine.field": f"{watermark_key}".strip(),
"hoodie.datasource.write.hive_style_partitioning": "true",
"hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.enable": "true",
"hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.database": param['dbname'],
"hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.table": "table",
"hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.partition_fields": param['table_partition_key'],
"hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.partition_extractor_class": "org.apache.hudi.hive.MultiPartKeysValueExtractor",
"hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.use_jdbc": "false",
"hoodie.schema.on.read.enable": "true",
"hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.mode": "hms"


According to our understanding that we got from AWS Documentation, the _rt table contains the real time data i.e. all the delta commits records that are not yet compacted, those data will also be available in the table, and the read optimised view contains only the data in the compacted files. So, how come we are getting the same records in both the views after each run, if we have set the compaction strategy as number of commits and the max inline delta commits value as 5 (mentioned in the above configurations). We have checked the delta commit files, it shows Compaction: false, then why we are seeing the same records in both the views?

The data you are trying to insert are they new records or are they updates?
